# How to add Dynamic Controls to MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am getting my List of Images from JSON and adding to page like below:

```
IEnumerable jsonData = default(IEnumerable);

            jsonData = GetJsonValues("http://www.viki.com/api/v2/channels.json");

            foreach (MovieDetails item in jsonData)
            {
                Image thumbNailImage = new Image();
                thumbNailImage.ImageUrl = item.Thumbnail;

                //this.Master.Controls.Add(thumbNailImage);
                this.Controls.Add(thumbNailImage);

            }
```

But this is adding the images at the buttom of the page as the page template comes from master page.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="VikiWeb._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    </asp:Content>
```

Now how do I add images in Master page.

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to add a control to your current page Controls collection ( i assume ). You can do this only in your Page_Init handler, any change to Controls Collection in events after Init will not make changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place an `asp:Panel` in MasterPage where you need the images to be rendered. And in the code-behind of your content page, do this

```
var panel = Master.FindControl("your_panel_id") as Panel;
if(panel != null)
{
    IEnumerable jsonData = default(IEnumerable);
    jsonData = GetJsonValues("http://www.viki.com/api/v2/channels.json");
    foreach (MovieDetails item in jsonData)
    {
        Image thumbNailImage = new Image();
        thumbNailImage.ImageUrl = item.Thumbnail;
        panel.Controls.Add(thumbNailImage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You place a [PlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx) in the position you like to add the controls, and add the controls similar to your code, but using this PlaceHolder id as:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="placeOnMe" />
```

and

```
placeOnMe.Controls.Add(thumbNailImage);
```